# bit operators with unsigned characters

Tags: c

```
unsigned char x = 93;
unsigned char a = x << 4;
printf("a = %d\n", a);
```

I do understand how bit operators work but I don't understand the binary representation of x.

How is a = 208?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
93 = 01011101
```

Shift that left 4 bits and it leaves the following (only 8 bits in your result):

```
11010000 = 208
```

Comment: `signed char` or `char` holds 8 bits as well?

Comment: @mateo:  Yes, both are 8 bits.

Comment: There are no signed chars in the question. If so, the result would have implementation-defined behavior.

Answer (score 3):

```
x = 93 = 0x5D = 0101 1101
         << 4 = 1101 0000
```

1101 0000 in decimal is 208.

Answer (score 1):

```
93 = 0x5d
0x5d << 4 = 0x5d0
0x5d0 & 0xff = 0xd0
0xd0 = 208
```

i.e. what has happened here is that the top bits have been cut off.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematically it corresponds to the following:

x<<4 is x*16, so x*16 = 93*16 = 1488

but a is an unsigned char (ie 0<=a<256), so a = 1488 modulo 256 = 208

Comment: This is the best answer, because it is closest to the way that C actually defines the result.

Answer (score 0):

That's because an unsigned char can only be as big as 255(1111 1111 in binary). If a number is left-shifted, all bits that go out of its bounds are lost. 0b11111111 << 1 = 0b11111110

So, if you get 93 in binary(0101 1101) and left shift it 4 times you'll get 1101 0000 -the 4 leftmost bits are forever lost.